# tensorflow sudden exposion of loss

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Hi I'm using Tensorflow to do machine learning task(Regression)

I'm using plain neural network and using ELU as a activation function.

But suddenly loss increases at certain point whenever I use ELU as a activation function.

using sigmoid activation, this doesn't happen.

**setting**

1. task : regression
2. learning rate = 0.05
3. optimizer = Adam
4. loss : MSE
5. network structure : plain NN with 4 hidden layer

whole code and log below!

- and there is more strange thing about epoch 64, I'm not sure why GPU log is printed again. this happens every time.

**Model Code**

```
class DeepModel:

    def __init__(self, learning_rate, batch_size, neighbor, weight_decay = 0.9, huber_delta=0.3, keep_prob_lst=[]):
        """ hyperparameters """
        self.isConv = False
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.input_size = neighbor * 3
        self.output_size = 1
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        self.layer1_size = 300
        self.layer2_size = 300
        self.layer3_size = 300
        self.layer4_size = 300
        self.huber_delta = huber_delta
        self.keep_prob_lst_val = keep_prob_lst
        self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name='global_step')

    def _create_placeholders(self):
        """ define the placeholders for input and output """
        with tf.name_scope("data"):
            self.input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [self.batch_size, self.input_size], name='input')
            self.output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [self.batch_size, self.output_size], name='output')
        with tf.name_scope("keep_prob"):
            self.keep_prob_lst = [ tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='layer{}_keep_prob'.format(idx+1)) for idx in range(len(self.keep_prob_lst_val))]

    def _create_weights(self):
        """ define weights. """
        # Assemble this part of the graph on the CPU. You can change it to GPU if you have GPU
        with tf.name_scope("weights"):
            self.W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.input_size, self.layer1_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer1_weight')
            self.b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.layer1_size]), name='layer1_bias')

            self.W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.layer1_size, self.layer2_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer2_weight')
            self.b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.layer2_size]), name='layer2_bias')

            self.W_3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.layer2_size, self.layer3_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer2_weight')
            self.b_3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.layer3_size]), name='layer2_bias')

            self.W_4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.layer3_size, self.layer4_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer2_weight')
            self.b_4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.layer4_size]), name='layer2_bias')

            self.W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.layer4_size, self.output_size], stddev=0.01, mean=0.0, seed=0), name='layer_out_weight')
            self.b_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,self.output_size]), name='layer_out_bias')

    def _create_loss(self):
        """ define the inference + the loss function """
        with tf.name_scope("loss"):
            self.layer1_output = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(self.input, self.W_1) + self.b_1)

            self.layer2_output = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(self.layer1_output, self.W_2) + self.b_2)

            self.layer3_output = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(self.layer2_output, self.W_3) + self.b_3)

            self.layer4_output = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(self.layer3_output, self.W_4) + self.b_4)

            self.layer_out_output = tf.matmul(self.layer4_output, self.W_out) + self.b_out
            self.se = 0.5 * tf.square(self.layer_out_output - self.output, name='square')
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.se)

    def _create_optimizer(self):
        """ define optimizer """
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.lr).minimize(self.loss, 
                                                      global_step=self.global_step)


    def build_graph(self):
        """ Build the graph for our model """
        self._create_placeholders()
        self._create_weights()
        self._create_loss()
        self._create_optimizer()
```

**Training code**

```
def train_deep(model, batch_gen, epoch_num, batch_size, batch_num, checkpoint_dir, graph_dir, skip_step):
    print('## Training deep Model')
    start_time = time.time()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    batches_seen = 0

    config=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_THREADS, log_device_placement=LOG_DEVICE_PLACEMENT)
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname(checkpoint_dir))
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        else:
            # create folder to store model weight
            os.system('mkdir {}'.format(checkpoint_dir))

        # writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(graph_dir, sess.graph)
        batches_seen = model.global_step.eval()
        current_epoch = int(batches_seen / batch_num)

        feed_dict={}
        for prob in zip(model.keep_prob_lst, model.keep_prob_lst_val):
                    feed_dict[prob[0]] = prob[1] 

        for epoch in xrange(current_epoch, epoch_num):
            total_loss = 0.0 
            epoch_time = time.time()
            for batch in xrange(batch_num):
                X_batch, Y_batch= batch_gen.next()
                feed_dict[model.input] = X_batch
                feed_dict[model.output] = Y_batch        
                loss_batch, _ = sess.run([model.loss, model.optimizer], 
                                                                    feed_dict=feed_dict)
                # writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=model.global_step.eval())
                total_loss += loss_batch

            # f.write('# Epoch {}  average loss and time : {:.7f}, {:.1f} seconds\n'.format(epoch, total_loss / batch_num, time.time() - epoch_time))
            print ('# Epoch {}  average loss and time : {:.7f}, {:.1f} seconds'.format(epoch, total_loss / batch_num, time.time() - epoch_time))

            if (epoch + 1) % skip_step == 0:
                saver.save(sess, checkpoint_dir + 'epoch', epoch, write_meta_graph = False)
        # writer.close()
        print('## Optimization Finished!')
        print('## Total time: {:.1f} seconds'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

**The total loss over training time**

```
# Epoch 0  average loss and time : 0.0247146, 196.3 seconds
# Epoch 1  average loss and time : 0.0044747, 196.2 seconds
# Epoch 2  average loss and time : 0.0047277, 186.7 seconds
# Epoch 3  average loss and time : 0.0044042, 188.7 seconds
# Epoch 4  average loss and time : 0.0044953, 188.2 seconds
# Epoch 5  average loss and time : 0.0044432, 194.8 seconds
# Epoch 6  average loss and time : 0.0045212, 194.8 seconds
# Epoch 7  average loss and time : 0.0045521, 187.3 seconds
# Epoch 8  average loss and time : 0.0047246, 174.0 seconds
# Epoch 9  average loss and time : 0.0045385, 175.2 seconds
# Epoch 10  average loss and time : 0.0045456, 181.9 seconds
# Epoch 11  average loss and time : 0.0045506, 169.9 seconds
# Epoch 12  average loss and time : 0.0045853, 172.5 seconds
# Epoch 13  average loss and time : 0.0045306, 171.0 seconds
# Epoch 14  average loss and time : 0.0044970, 171.2 seconds
# Epoch 15  average loss and time : 0.0045254, 171.5 seconds
# Epoch 16  average loss and time : 0.0044871, 169.4 seconds
# Epoch 17  average loss and time : 0.0045064, 170.4 seconds
# Epoch 18  average loss and time : 0.0045122, 194.6 seconds
# Epoch 19  average loss and time : 0.0045325, 171.7 seconds
# Epoch 20  average loss and time : 0.0044945, 194.5 seconds
# Epoch 21  average loss and time : 0.0045799, 194.8 seconds
# Epoch 22  average loss and time : 0.0044225, 171.6 seconds
# Epoch 23  average loss and time : 0.0045016, 171.3 seconds
# Epoch 24  average loss and time : 0.0044856, 172.7 seconds
# Epoch 25  average loss and time : 0.0044534, 173.9 seconds
# Epoch 26  average loss and time : 0.0044783, 193.3 seconds
# Epoch 27  average loss and time : 0.0044508, 191.4 seconds
# Epoch 28  average loss and time : 0.0044432, 170.9 seconds
# Epoch 29  average loss and time : 0.0044638, 173.0 seconds
# Epoch 30  average loss and time : 0.0044592, 172.8 seconds
# Epoch 31  average loss and time : 0.0043936, 174.0 seconds
# Epoch 32  average loss and time : 0.0044174, 172.7 seconds
# Epoch 33  average loss and time : 0.0044253, 172.1 seconds
# Epoch 34  average loss and time : 0.0043917, 171.7 seconds
# Epoch 35  average loss and time : 0.0044062, 171.9 seconds
# Epoch 36  average loss and time : 0.0044309, 171.7 seconds
# Epoch 37  average loss and time : 0.0043879, 174.5 seconds
# Epoch 38  average loss and time : 0.0043931, 186.0 seconds
# Epoch 39  average loss and time : 95.0471165, 171.2 seconds
# Epoch 40  average loss and time : 0.0129813, 171.2 seconds
# Epoch 41  average loss and time : 0.0115643, 171.3 seconds
# Epoch 42  average loss and time : 0.0106565, 172.0 seconds
# Epoch 43  average loss and time : 0.0098280, 172.5 seconds
# Epoch 44  average loss and time : 0.0090725, 171.9 seconds
# Epoch 45  average loss and time : 0.0083836, 171.5 seconds
# Epoch 46  average loss and time : 0.0077587, 170.9 seconds
# Epoch 47  average loss and time : 0.0071937, 170.8 seconds
# Epoch 48  average loss and time : 0.0066826, 171.4 seconds
# Epoch 49  average loss and time : 0.0062041, 178.2 seconds
# Epoch 50  average loss and time : 0.0057936, 182.3 seconds
# Epoch 51  average loss and time : 0.0054678, 195.1 seconds
# Epoch 52  average loss and time : 0.0053669, 171.2 seconds
# Epoch 53  average loss and time : 0.0051792, 172.1 seconds
# Epoch 54  average loss and time : 0.0051216, 194.4 seconds
# Epoch 55  average loss and time : 0.0050883, 194.8 seconds
# Epoch 56  average loss and time : 0.0049717, 171.6 seconds
# Epoch 57  average loss and time : 0.0049208, 186.9 seconds
# Epoch 58  average loss and time : 0.0050312, 170.8 seconds
# Epoch 59  average loss and time : 0.0048330, 170.5 seconds
# Epoch 60  average loss and time : 0.0049766, 170.1 seconds
# Epoch 61  average loss and time : 0.0049494, 171.2 seconds
# Epoch 62  average loss and time : 0.0049745, 171.1 seconds
# Epoch 63  average loss and time : 0.0052638, 171.4 seconds
# Epoch 64  average loss and tiI tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:89:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:89:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:89:00.0)
me : 0.0044675, 171.4 seconds
# Epoch 65  average loss and time : 0.0051712, 171.2 seconds
# Epoch 66  average loss and time : 0.0045092, 171.4 seconds
# Epoch 67  average loss and time : 0.0049986, 171.4 seconds
# Epoch 68  average loss and time : 0.0050070, 171.2 seconds
# Epoch 69  average loss and time : 0.0047540, 170.0 seconds
# Epoch 70  average loss and time : 0.0051099, 194.4 seconds
# Epoch 71  average loss and time : 0.0044266, 171.3 seconds
# Epoch 72  average loss and time : 0.0052696, 193.5 seconds
# Epoch 73  average loss and time : 0.0044099, 171.9 seconds
# Epoch 74  average loss and time : 0.0054506, 194.5 seconds
# Epoch 75  average loss and time : 0.0044097, 194.8 seconds
# Epoch 76  average loss and time : 0.0048847, 193.7 seconds
# Epoch 77  average loss and time : 0.0044050, 176.3 seconds
# Epoch 78  average loss and time : 0.0050718, 194.3 seconds
# Epoch 79  average loss and time : 0.0043967, 171.6 seconds
# Epoch 80  average loss and time : 0.0045824, 188.8 seconds
# Epoch 81  average loss and time : 0.0049379, 172.6 seconds
# Epoch 82  average loss and time : 0.0047899, 194.5 seconds
# Epoch 83  average loss and time : 0.0045796, 193.2 seconds
# Epoch 84  average loss and time : 0.0046792, 195.2 seconds
# Epoch 85  average loss and time : 0.0049916, 195.4 seconds
# Epoch 86  average loss and time : 0.0044301, 194.1 seconds
# Epoch 87  average loss and time : 0.0047661, 170.6 seconds
# Epoch 88  average loss and time : 0.0047771, 173.3 seconds
# Epoch 89  average loss and time : 0.0044409, 172.3 seconds
# Epoch 90  average loss and time : 0.0045383, 176.0 seconds
# Epoch 91  average loss and time : 0.0046460, 171.4 seconds
# Epoch 92  average loss and time : 0.0046248, 194.0 seconds
# Epoch 93  average loss and time : 0.0045983, 195.3 seconds
# Epoch 94  average loss and time : 0.0046806, 172.9 seconds
# Epoch 95  average loss and time : 0.0045397, 187.3 seconds
# Epoch 96  average loss and time : 0.0044473, 171.4 seconds
# Epoch 97  average loss and time : 0.0047241, 171.9 seconds
# Epoch 98  average loss and time : 0.0045720, 171.3 seconds
# Epoch 99  average loss and time : 0.0045641, 171.3 seconds
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

How do I debug this? manually check weights?

Comment: Could you provide us with the code that produces this error, or at least some information on your training parameters (learning rate, batch size, ...) and the data you are using for the training. This might help to track down the problem. Maybe you have chosen the learning rate too high. Does the explosion of the loss not occur if you use ReLU for example?

Comment: @ml4294 Thank you for answer. I just posted my code and whole training loss log, using Adam, which performed best among RMSProp and Adadelta, I think loss converges good with learning rate 0.05 as loss remains low all the time. I'm currently doing same thing with RELU, I'll post the result. I think there is no problem with my code. I really want to know why that happened and how to figure it out.

Comment: @ml4294 using ReLU didn't had that problem

Comment: Ok, this is a bit strange. The only difference is the handling of negative inputs. Did you try initializing the weight matrices with mainly positive values, for example mean=0.2, stddev=0.04? Does this yield a difference between ReLU and ELU?

Comment: @ml4294 I'll try and tell you thank you. I can utilize only one GPU so it's gonna take while

Comment: and should bias term should be positive too? like 0.1. my data's independent & dependent variables are all scaled within 0~1. does this make any difference? some native numerical calculation error or something

Comment: This should not be a problem in my opinion. You can try a positive initialization for the biases, too, but I don't think that it is necessary.